# Query runs slow unless new column is created, data copied in then old column replaced

Tags: sql-server

History - Original database was built in SQL Server 2012 but now running in SQL Server 2019

Tables were huge but a lot of data has since been deleted.

A query was running really slowly and through investigation an INT column that was used to connect various tables when changed to a varchar improved the performance greatly and so it was changed.

Now however when new data is added into the table the query runs extremely slow again - (around 20 seconds)

To solve I need to create a brand new varchar column, copy the data across then delete the old column and rename the new one to the original name. Then all is well (UNTIL THE NEXT IMPORT)

This is extremely annoying and must be to do with indexing or corrupt data somewhere whereby creating the new column solves it but it's only temporary.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Attempted backing up database, shrinking files, rebuilding indexes

Comment: Without some details of your tables about all anybody can do is guess. Table definitions, including indexes along with some sample data is a needed as a bare minimum. I suspect you have some other things going as well.

Comment: It can be that when you insert a lot of data, it triggers statistics recompilation which isn't performed until next time someone tries to query. You can usually see if this is the issue by doing: 1) insert 2) select 3) quickly check Activity Monitor in Management Studio and choose Display Query Plan. If you get error on query plan, it's probably recalculating statistics.

It sounds like it might be useful to rebuild your table by running ALTER TABLE xxx REBUILD PK

Comment: It's tough to go into detail and I have several other databases using the exact same structure with no issue. That also could be part of the problem as this database would have been a replication of another one initially so the issue will be something behind the scenes but beyond my knowledge. I've worked with SQL Server for over 20 years and this is the first I am seeing this issue. I am importing about 400 rows of data into a temp table first and then inserting into the main table from there via a looped insert statement. I tried rebuilding the indexes after the last import but no success